# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'conference' not found. 'conference' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm working on my project and I got stuck on this issue and have no ideas how to solve it.

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link {% if 'conference' in segment %} active {% endif %}" href="{% url 'conference' %}">
    <i class="ni ni-collection  text-blue"></i>
    <span class="nav-link-text">Конференц зал</span>
```

I got [error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cQC7.png).

[structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xop2H.png)
[continuation of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D03D.png)
SEE THE STRUCTURE OF PROJECT

views.py of conference app

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse


@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    context = {'segment': 'conference'}

    html_template = loader.get_template('conference/conference.html')
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))


@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):
    context = {}
    # All resource paths end in .html.
    # Pick out the html file name from the url. And load that template.
    try:

        load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]

        if load_template == 'admin':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:index'))
        context['segment'] = load_template

        html_template = loader.get_template('home/' + load_template)
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:

        html_template = loader.get_template('home/page-404.html')
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except:
        html_template = loader.get_template('home/page-500.html')
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

[urls.py of conference app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsDbU.png)
[urls.py of home app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osmHr.png)

urls.py of conference app

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('conference/', index, name='conference'),
    # Other URL patterns for your app's views...
]
```

All my apps are in apps folder. I have one folder for all templates of apps and inside of that I have templates with name of app, there I have html files of apps. I have app of home page. I don't know why but when I write here 'home' instead of 'conference', everything works, but home page are being opened. If you have questions and need more details, ask please. What's wrong with my code, may be I should adjust my views.py of conference app?   Thanks in advance!

```
<a class="nav-link {% if 'conference' in segment %} active {% endif %}" href="{% url 'home' %}">
```

Comment: Please add project structure

Comment: I added structure, please check the screenshots of structure

Comment: Do you have `home` url in the same `urls.py` file? If that's true show how it looks like together with the `conference` path. Also show were the `home` is defined.

Comment: Of which app is urls and view you added ?

Comment: I added views and urls of conference app

Comment: Home app is defined in apps folder with other apps of website

Comment: can you try this for the url template? change the value to: '`app_name:conference`' make sure to replace app_name with the name of your app and make sure that the app is present in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Reverse url is app:urlname no matter if the template is “within the app”. You should do:

```
{% url ‘conference:conference’ %}
```

As per you project structure.

Also make sure that your conferences urls.py is registered in the cores urls.py.

Comment: I tried to write url like you texted - {% url ‘conference:conference’ %}. It did not work

Comment: Yes, I registered urls of conference in core folder.